# Running JUnit test with JVM 1.6 under Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, java-6

I have a legacy application that absolutely must compile and run in JVM 1.6.

But it not enough to specify `-source 6 -target 6` to a newer compiler (8, 11, 16 whatever JDK version newer than 1.6).

I really need to develop and test in a "concrete"† JVM 1.6, in my case: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode), because the server hosting this application cannot get a JVM update.

I've managed to configure maven to do it all (the `maven.compiler.*` properties and the `maven-toolchains-plugin`) and everything works fine (`mvn test` -wise):

```
[...]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ [...] ---
[INFO] Toolchain in surefire-plugin: JDK[openjdk-1.6.0-unofficial-b31-windows-amd64-image]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: [...]\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running [...]Test
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.149 sec
[...]
```

To be really comfortable however, I need to run the unit tests (junit 4.13.2 + mockito-inline 2.8.47 +  powermock 1.7.4) inside Eclipse. But it errors with the following output:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/RemoteTestRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Exception in thread "main"
```

I can only guess that Eclipse tries to inject some `TestRunner` (indeed a `RemoteTestRunner`) in my application classpath when running the tests, which was compiled under for a newer JVM (class file version 52, which IIRC is compatible with java 8 upwards).

**Is there a official/unofficial configuration or workaround for this?**

† It's fun to apply "concrete" quality to a "virtual" machine haha.

PS: In vscode I get the very same error (yes, even the "org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/RemoteTestRunner" part and the line numbers in stacktrace), with the addition of the message "Could not find the main class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner. Program will exit.".

Comment: I'm open to install an earlier version of Eclipse (or even vscode) if I knew the last version that worked with java-6. This compatibility matrix however is not easy to find (for mockito and powermock, for instance, I resorted to binary search until I got the versions right).

Comment: Do you know that you can run Eclipse itself under a different JVM than you use for developing and running your code/applications? In your project in Eclipse, have you specified the 1.6 JVM that you're targeting? If you don't do that, applications use whatever Java is running Eclipse, by default.

Comment: @E-Riz yes. My Eclipse actually runs in a jvm 16 (java.vm.version=16.0.2+7-67). Eclipse grabs all jvm version configuration from maven. I've configured installed JREs and execution environments (JavaSE-1.6 specifically). These are all set, and all ok. Actually there lies the problem: eclipse indeed uses jvm 6 to run my tests (as I asked it to do, by means of maven configuration); but I guess eclipse classes were not compiled for java 6, whence the classfile version greater than 50.0. I'm looking for either a workaround or the last eclipse version still compiled for 50.0.

Comment: @E-Riz by the way: I cannot run this version of Eclipse (2022-03 (4.23.0)) in anything lower than jvm 11.

Comment: Does running the tests from within Eclipse via Maven work for you as shown here? https://youtu.be/GnNnQY5ujFg?t=370

Comment: @howlger no it doesn't work, because Eclipse is dumb enough to try to run maven itself in JVM 6, which does not work for this version of maven (whichever version it is): `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` (that maven was compiled using jdk 7). On the command line `mvn test` works though, because maven itself is using java 11, and it forks JVM 6 (per `maven-toolchains-plugin` configuration).

Comment: @howlger but by running a mvn build within Eclipse specially crafted to use a newer JVM it worked! Well, worked just like it does on the terminal (aka command line), forking JVM 6 along the way. At least the stacktraces are now clickable inside Eclipse! I think this is enough as a workaround. No line code coverage unfortunately.

Comment: Per someone suggestion (whose comment has been deleted now), I've tried in neon.3, and it works. Then I binary searched some versions. Known to work: neon.3, oxygen.3a, photon.r, 2019-12.r, 2021-03.r (the last one working with JVM 6). Known to not work: 2021-06.r, 2021-09.r, 2021-12.r and 2022-03.r. So, I'm sticking with 2021-03.r now, with full junit support + code coverage, using jvm 6.